# INITIALIZE gives garbage value on PIC X and PIC S9 COMP variables

Tags: cobol

When initializing the following variables:

```
01  BATCH-REC.
       03  BATCH-VERSION             PIC X(2).
       03  BATCH-FIELDS              PIC X(682).
       03  BATCH-REC-01 REDEFINES BATCH-FIELDS.
           05  B01-OH-DTL-REC.
               07  B01-PE-ID         PIC X(12).
               07  B01-PMT-DISC-TERMS PIC S9(4) COMP.
               07  B01-PMT-DISC-AMT  PIC S9(18) COMP.
```

using the command

```
INITIALIZE BATCH-REC.
```

the variables `B01-PMT-DISC-TERMS` is initialized to value +08224 and `B01-PMT-DISC-AMT` is initialized to +314885530818453536. 
What could the reason be? Would it be a good idea to MOVE a blank space to those variables after initializing? I dont want to change that BATCH-REC code to add a default value on them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `INITIALIZE` statement will not initialize redefined fields. If you want the redefined fields to be initialized, you must identify them in some way. For example,

```
INITIALIZE BATCH-VERSION BATCH-REC-01
```

This will initialize the elementary fields to `SPACES` or `ZEROS` depending on their `PICTURE`. `BATCH-FIELDS` will not be initialized.

---

Item 3, below applies, in this case. From the 2002 standard for `INITIALIZE`:

> 5) The receiving-operand in each implicit MOVE or SET statement is determined by applying the following steps in order:
>
> a) First, the following data items are excluded as receiving-operands:
>
> 1. Any identifiers that are not valid receiving operands of a MOVE statement, except data items of category data-pointer, object-reference, or program-pointer.
> 2. If the FILLER phrase is not specified, elementary data items with an explicit or implicit FILLER clause.
> 3. Any elementary data item subordinate to identifier-1 whose data description entry contains a REDEFINES or RENAMES clause or is subordinate to a data item whose data description entry contains a REDEFINES clause. However, identifier-1 may itself have a REDEFINES clause or be subordinate to a data item with a REDEFINES clause.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you Rick

Answer (score 5):

In this case I think you will find your INITIALIZE statement did initialize your PIC X data to spaces.  The value you have for B01-PMT-DISC-TERMS is x'2020' and the value for B01-PMT-DISC-AMT is x'2020202020202020' with the leading digit cut off, possibly due to reporting of the value being limited to the picture clause of 18 digits.

Regardless, I agree with @RickSmith and believe he is correct in his solution to your problem.